# Custom JQuery inputmask including time

Tags: jquery-inputmask

I'm using JQuery Robin Herbots' plugin. Please help me create period mask with placeholder:
`"dd:hh:mm"`.
Where "dd" allows any number of days(from 0 to infinity),
"hh" - hours(00-23),
"mm" - minutes (00-59).
Tried via regex, but failed join it with placeholder. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will help someone spend less time on researching topic. Correct mask is:

```
$('#element').inputmask({
        mask: "9{1,10}:h:eg",
        clearIncomplete: true,
        definitions: {
            '9': {placeholder: "дд"},
            'h': {placeholder: "ч"},
            'e': {validator: "[0-5]", placeholder: "м"},
            'g': {validator: "[0-9]", placeholder: "м"}
        }
    });
```